# Java servlet doGet() not refreshing after first call

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I am making AJAX calls to a Java servlet at a set interval. Inside the doGet it querys a DB, puts the results in JSON format, and returns them. This works great on the first try (when the page is first loaded or refreshed) but at every ajax call after it returns the same data as the first call even if things were added.

Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("in");

    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from chatroom");
        JSONObject jsonPosts = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray postList = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject post;

        while (rs.next()) {
            post = new JSONObject();
            post.put("user", rs.getString("user"));
            post.put("text", rs.getString("text"));
            post.put("time", rs.getString("time"));

            postList.add(post);
        }

        System.out.println(postList.toString());

        response.setContentType("application/json");

        response.getWriter().write(postList.toString());

        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        cnfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException sqe) {
        sqe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Javascript:

```
            setInterval(function () {

                getChat();

            }, 6000);


                function getChat() {

                var posts;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "getChat",
                    data: "position=hi",
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {



                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                        {
                            $("#chatWindow").append(data[i].text + "<br/>");
                        }
                    }

                });


            }
```

Comment: Also if you notice the "System.out.print" in the doGet on the servlet. That is only printing out to Netbeans server log once, not sure if thats just the was the log works or if it is indeed only being called once. Because the data (same data) is being returned each call on the javascript side.

Comment: what you get in response in `data` for first call /

Comment: It may be an issue with the browser cache. Check the HTTP headers that you may use to signal the browser that the URL contents should not be retrieved from cache.

Comment: If you are updating something in database, you should make the Ajax call as PUT instead of GET.

Comment: @pushya it is understood that he is updating the DB through other ways; in the code here there are no updates or inserts.

Comment: I would check with the browser developer tools and check how many times the request is being sent.

Comment: @SJuan76 You were indeed correct I didnt think about the browser cache. I put a simple "cache: false" in the Ajax call and it started working...always the simple things. If you want to put that as an answer Ill mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the same data when repeating the same requests usually is an issue with a cache (let it be in the browser, the server or in a proxy).

Several ways of avoiding cache's effect:

- Disable them (generally not a good idea since it causes a performance impact).
- Use HTTP headers that signal to the browser that the content should not be cached / that previous cached data is stale.
- For AJAX, use the `cache: false` parameter.
- If all of the above fails, add a bogus parameter to the URL so the browser interprets it as a request of a different resource(v.g., `url: "getChat" + (new Date()).getTime()`)